# Java JodaTime Period Formatting

Tags: java, jodatime

In Joda time, I need to find the difference between 2 periods:

```
  PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendHours().appendSuffix(":").appendMinutes().appendSuffix(":").appendSeconds()
            .toFormatter();
  Period period1 = formatter.parsePeriod("11:20:50");
  Period period2 = formatter.parsePeriod("13:40:00");
  Period difference1 = period1.minus(period2).normalizedStandard();
  System.out.println(formatter.print(difference1));  //shows -02:-19:-10
```

The result is `-02:-19:-10` but I want to show as `-02:19:10`. Is there any formatting I can do in JodaTime to achieve that?

Comment: Maybe you find [this alternative](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/9e87a4d98d105d53dd37) interesting. I agree with you that negative durations should only show the sign in front, not between the components. XML-Schema has the same expectation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can configure the PeriodFormatter to do this by itself.
But you can check if the normalized period has a negative length. If so, you add the minus sign yourself, and the append the formatted version of the *negated* period (so in this case, negating the period makes it positive)

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2)
        .appendHours().appendSuffix(":").appendMinutes().appendSuffix(":").appendSeconds()
        .toFormatter();
Period period1 = formatter.parsePeriod("11:20:50");
Period period2 = formatter.parsePeriod("13:40:00");
Period difference1 = period1.minus(period2).normalizedStandard();
String formatted;
if (difference1.toStandardSeconds().get(DurationFieldType.seconds()) < 0) {
    formatted = "-" + formatter.print(difference1.negated());
} else {
    formatted = formatter.print(difference1);
}
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Comment: the joda Period.negated() not support in joda version 1.6.2? is there any alternative for the method?